# How to remove cache when reloading page in Firefox with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, firefox, browser-cache

Up until now, I had always sent an AJAX request and run `location.reload()` when the request is finished, updating the page. Recently, for some reason, the old input values are still kept when the page is reload. I suspect the culprit is Firefox's cache, because when I remove the cache or just reload the page normally with F5, the input values are updated as well. The same function still work on Chrome and Edge.

I tried out `window.location.href = window.location.href`, same thing happened.

I tried out `window.location.replace(window.location.href)`, same thing happened.

I did my research and saw some people suggested `location.reload(true)`, it worked perfectly. However, I also read that this method is deprecated and had been removed in some browsers already. I don't want to build my code base on such uncertainty.

Cache busting technique can lead to caching overhead, and I don't want to slow down the page performance.

Thus, my question is: **which code can I write to tell the browser to do a forced reload, removing all cache?**

I only want to remove cache in some functions, not all of them. I am not a fan of form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read about the reload not being supported, however this seems to suggest it's fine (please someone correct me if I'm misunderstanding here, it's probably on Firefox support guaranteed): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

I've also used it and never had issues, serving Chrome and Edge.

You could also try adding dummy data to the end of your URL on reload, with use of ?, although I have not used this method myself.

In future projects front-end frameworks such as Vue, React, etc, will allow you to use State, which can prevent the whole reloading situation, might be worth checking out in future.

Comment: The reload function worked fine in Firefox until recently. It still worked in Chrome and Edge, I can confirm of that.
I did look into cache busting, and couldn't be willing to use it with all the cons it got.
I did know about Vue React etc, however my project is too big and I don't have enough time to rebuild it with those frameworks.

Comment: Cache busting through query strings shouldn't have the cons associated. What specific cons do you anticipate ?

Comment: https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting According to this website and the reference link from this web, in section 3 "Query strings", cache busting will hurt performance and reduce accessibility, which I really want to avoid.

Comment: Query strings changing would be same performance as the old location.reload(true), as it just re-pulls that data, treating it as a new download. I'm 99.999% sure you'll be fine with this unless you're running NASA level stuff :D

Comment: If you said so I will give it a try. Thanks!